# Java one child class containing other siblings

Tags: java, inheritance

I saw some code has a child class that contains other siblings.  For example, Child1 below contains its siblings Child2, Child3.  I wonder if there is any problem with this design?

```
public class Parent
{
   ...
}

public final class Child1 extends Parent
{
  private Child2 child2;
  private Child3 child3;
  ...
}

public final class Child2 extends Parent
{
  ...
}

public final class Child3 extends Parent
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not really. Is there something in particular you are worried about?

Comment: Why should there be any problem?

Comment: I think it mostly depends on what you are trying to do with the children classes. Nevertheless, I am a little confused about the `()` in the class declarations

Comment: The use of "contains" might be misleading: Better if you'd say "has an attribute of type" or "refers to"

Comment: This is difficult to say without knowing the intent of the code...

Comment: you see, OO is just a way to model real-world semantics into some logical programming structure. This structure you're presenting does not have any problem "per se". Now, if you provide us some context info, then we can give you an opinion about how adequate the model is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted from a technical point of view, but it makes me question whether this is the right way to model your domain. From your domain's point of view does it make sense for a Child1 to be talking to a Child2 and Child3? Or is this just a mechanism for separating out your code into logical sections?

Also big inheritance trees should be avoided where possible as inheritance is the strongest form of coupling. Perhaps you could implement the same functionality using the strategy pattern to reduce the coupling.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make different classes for siblings. If tomorrow someone have four siblings then you will be making four classes. This will result in Class Exposion.

You can have your design like:

**Parent Class:**

```
public class Parent{

   ...
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
public final class Child extends Parent{

  private List<Child> siblings;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I assume OP was talking about the tree of his inheritance structure rather than modelling a parent child relationship.